# Root aggregate problem in domain driven design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have two Entities Publisher and SocialAccount , both are independent and having relationship of Many to Many. Both are root Aggregates , now i cannot get social account through Publisher and I want to convert M To M relationship to 1 To M. So I Introduced another entity Registration , will have {PubID, SocID, CreateDate}. Now there is 1 To M relationship between Publisher and Registration and 1 to 1 between Registration and SocialAccount. so publisher will have

> List  <Registrations> _Registrations {get;set;}

But when I create aggregate boundaries, Publisher is my root and according to aggregate principle, only root aggregate will hold reference to another root aggregate. But here Registration hold reference.

So do i am violating aggregate principle , because registration is connected Social Account entity.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of aggregate concept appears to be incorrect.  Objects within an aggregate can in fact hold references to other aggregates.  The rule is an external object cannot hold a reference to something within an aggregate.

On the Registration object, you seem to have created it to avoid some aggregate to aggregate relationships.  That is not why you create an object.  If there is in fact a Registration in your domain, create it and model it.  If it is not in your domain, don't add it just to traverse some path.

Having added Registration, you say it cannot hold a reference to Social Account because it is part of Publisher.  That is not the rule, but more important how did Registration suddenly become part of the Publisher aggregate anyway?  By virtue only of Publisher having a Registration collection?

An aggregate is a group of objects that are treated as one unit for maintaining state and invariants.  Existence of a relationship by itself does not confer membership in an aggregate.

But look at the other side now.  Registration is 1 to 1 with Social Account.  And if we remove a Social Account does it ever make sense to still have a Registration with a Publisher?  If not then Registration probably is in fact part of the SocialAccount aggregate instead.  That is why we create aggregates - to ensure objects and their relationships are always valid after a state change.   If the change of state of removing a SocialAccount includes removing all Registrations associated with that account, we would want to include it in the aggregate to enforce that rule.

Now you have indeed violated the "aggregate rule" - you have an external relationship from Publisher to an object, Registration,  that is an internal part of the SocialAccount aggregate.

These concepts are more than just rules, they have reasons.  You need to review what aggregate really means, understand what the rules actually say and what they really mean, why they exist in the first place.  Then reevaluate your relationships and aggregate definitions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First we need an abstraction for encapsulating references within the model.

An AGGREGATE is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes.

Each AGGREGATE has a root and a boundary. The boundary defines what is inside the AGGREGATE. The root is a single, specific ENTITY contained in the AGGREGATE. The root is the only member of the AGGREGATE that outside objects are allowed to hold references to, although objects within the boundary may hold references to each other. ENTITIES other than the root have local identity, but that identity needs to be distinguishable only within the AGGREGATE, because no outside object can ever see it out of the context of the root ENTITY.

what you think about it Ssyphus?

Comment: That is essentially the aggregate definition proposed by Evans.  Personally I find the global versus local identity aspect am little confusing and prefer to emphasize no references obtained other than a transient one and a contained entity is only by accessible by traversal via the aggregate root.